# Why does Comic Yuri Hime release 2 months ahead of time?

Tags: manga-production

I know that the shoujo ao/yuri serialized comic, Comic Yuri Hime is released on the 18 of each month according to [their website](http://www.ichijinsha.co.jp/yurihime/)

> コミック百合姫
>   毎月18日発売
>   本体780円+税
>
> **Google Translation:**
>
> Comic Yurihime
>   released on the 18 th of every month 
>   Main body ¥ 780 + tax

however one thing i noticed which is strange is that they seem to release 2 months ahead of time than what is labeled. ie, the [January 18th 2018 issue](https://www.jbox.com/pap920?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email) is labeled as March 2018

[image: Comic Yuri Hime Marcher 2018]

since this was released in January, why was it released (or at least labeled) as March rather than January?

Comment: This is widespread among manga and many other types of magazine; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_date.